# Xcode does not recognize PoDoFo built for iOS

Tags: c++, ios, cross-compiling, podofo

I've cross-compiled the PoDoFo (https://github.com/podofo/podofo) library for iOS using conan with the following profiles:

```
Profile host:
[settings]
arch=armv8
build_type=Release
compiler=apple-clang
compiler.libcxx=libc++
compiler.version=15
os=iOS
os.sdk=iphoneos
os.version=15.0

Profile build:
[settings]
arch=armv8
build_type=Release
compiler=apple-clang
compiler.cppstd=gnu17
compiler.libcxx=libc++
compiler.version=15
os=Macos
```

Xcode gives me the following build error when I add the resulting libpodofo.0.11.0.dylib in my project:

```
ld: building for 'iOS', but linking in dylib (/Users/tarlanismayilsoy/Documents/iOS Projects/.../Resources/Podofo/libpodofo.0.11.0.dylib) built for 'macOS'
```

I don't understand why Xcode is complaining since I've built the library for iOS, not MacOS (see the profiles above). I'd appreciate it if someone with cross-compilation experience could help.

Comment: How did the file in "..." get there? And what kind of help did you expect from us beyond "Yup, that library is compiled for the wrong OS".

Comment: I've dragged the PoDoFo dylib and header files into my Xcode project. I also created a bridging header to call PoDoFo functions from my code. I expect to get an explanation regarding why the library was compiled for the wrong OS despite the Conan profile being correct.

Comment: You haven't showed us how you invoked conan and what the compile output was so how is anyone supposed to produce an explanation?